# Alguem sabe resolver esse erro ao buildar projeto flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, apk, build

Realizei build do meu projeto flutter e me deparei com este erro alguem pode me ajudar?

C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk
Running "flutter pub get" in auto_home...                           1,6s
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
To generate an app bundle, run:
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
To split the APKs per ABI, run:
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 326KB to 299KB: Removed 8%

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':path_provider:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\Sarah.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b60f613031a9e1950cc2947d9ba526e8\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

```
 C:\Users\Sarah\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b60f613031a9e1950cc2947d9ba526e8\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          123,8s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: Parece ser um erro com esse pacote path_provider. Você está usando a versão mais recente? (```path_provider: ^1.6.24```) Experimente também rodar um ```flutter clean``` antes de compilar de novo.

Comment: Obrigada,  atualizei o path_provider e deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo as instruções detalhadas [nesta](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31300) issue, certifique-se de estar utilizando a versão mais recente do pacote [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider).

Em seu arquivo `pubspec.yaml`, verifique:

```
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
```

Após isso, lembre-se de rodar `flutter clean` antes de gerar a próxima build.